# Mounting a network dir locally on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn

I am using a VPN connection.

The place I'm connecting to has two computers I want to access via SSH in tty mode. Furthermore, they have some files I want to edit locally.

Is there a way to mount my home folder on one of those computers locally, so I can use it seamlessly as if it were local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have KDE or just use Konqueror you can acces remote folder like this: fish://user@host

> Finally, Konqueror can act as a file manager for local files but also, through FTP, WebDAV or other protocols, as a file manager for files on remote machines. The FISH ("fish://user@host") protocol can be used to manipulate files through SSH, allowing you to use Konqueror as the file manager for almost any machine you can connect to on the internet.

Source: Konqueror features page

Another option is mounting with FUSE and SSHFS.
SSHFS uses SFTP.
Article in [Linux journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8904) and shorter tutorial on [Blog](http://www.staldal.nu/tech/2010/08/21/mount-your-home-directory-with-sshfs-in-linux/):

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mkdir randombox_home
$ sshfs  matt@my.randombox.com:  randombox_home
matt@my.randombox.com's password: ************
```